# Could anyone please assist me on the webpack configuration?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader

I am trying to configure webpack for my project (I'm going through colt steele webpack course on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnS_1lolc44). But I'm not able to configure my images properly, I tried everything and looked everywhere on Internet but not able to figure out how to solve. Below is my directory structure and code snippet.

I have three webpack config files: **webpack.common.js, webpack.dev.js and webpack.prod.js**

**webpack.common.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    plugins : [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/template.html"
    })],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ["style-loader","css-loader","sass-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                      name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
                      publicPath: '/',
                      outputPath: 'img',
                      esModule: false
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ["html-loader"]
            }              
        ]
    }
}
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const common = require('./webpack.common');
const {merge} = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        filename: "main.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    }
})
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const common = require('./webpack.common');
const {merge} = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: "production",
    output: {
        filename: "main.[contenthash].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    }
})
```

My src dir structure is as :

[image]

I'm importing all of my sass and other js files through **src/index.js** file like below :

[image]

And I'm calling my images in src/template.html file as

[image]

All images are present in src/img folder and template.html file is calling the images through the path as "./img/."

When I run npm build command, I get the dist folder created as :

[image]

Here, one thing which confuses me is why images are getting generated twice. One inside the dist/img folder with proper name + hashvalue + extension and one inside the dist folder.
Also my generated index.html file is calling the images present in the dist folder (which are incorrect one and why getting generated I'm not sure about) instead of calling the images present in dist/img folder ?

[image]

Above screenshot is of the generated dist/index.html file. Here, the image path is for the images generated in the dist folder which is not the correct one.

And even I try to open these generated images (present in dist folder) in VS code, I will get the error message "An error occured while loading the image". While images present in dist/img folder, shows me the correct image on selecting any one.

Could anyone please help me in understanding here, why webpack is generating two sets of images (one is correct and another one is incorrect) and why generated dist/index.html file is looking for the path of incorrect images not the correct one.

GitHub Repo : git@github.com:Guru4741/Sedna.git

Thanks

Comment: Could you create a GH repo where the error is reproduced?

Comment: Sure. I have edited my question and put link of repo below. Its in the main branch. Thanks for reply @Andrei

Comment: Thanks for the repo, I'll investigate. Meanwhile I've seen that `file-loader` is [deprecated in v5](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/).

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I'm trying with the new updates. Thanks for sharing. Please do share about your findings. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, it may take a while, but I'll share everything I find in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using webpack 5 and there are big changes. You have a lot of errors in the code, but find it yourself;)
One more remark. This "node_modules" does not commit to github :)

Okay, let's get to why the pictures don't appear.
Remove the "file-loader" library, then remove this part of the code:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
  use: [{
    loader: "file-loader",
    options: {
      name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
      publicPath: '/',
      outputPath: 'img',
      esModule: false
    }
  }]
},
```

Replace with this:

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
  type: 'asset/resource',
  generator: {
    filename: 'img/[name][ext]',
  },
}
```

You can learn more about the asset visit this page [asset-modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/)

And one more thing, the course you are watching is quite old 2019, the basics are the same everywhere, but there are a lot of changes in the new webpack 5.